# Prevent apache from replacing fully qualified server name with localhost?

Tags: macos, apache, url-rewriting

I have installed MAMP on High Sierra, on `myserver.mycollege.edu`

If I point my browser (chrome) to `http://myserver.mycollege.edu/some/path`, what shows up in the address bar is `localhost/some/path`.

And if `some/path/index.html` contains a link to `myserver.mycollege.edu/some/other/page`, that gets replaced with `localhost/some/other/page`

This happens for other users, when accessing my content from their own machine! This obviously fails because their browser is now trying to access a web server on their own machine instead of mine.

So my question is, what is responsible for this URL rewrite, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I should have mentioned is that `some/path` is mediawiki-1.28.1.
The top page served out of that directory is index.php, which will do some config things as part of serving its top level page.

`localhost` was actually hard coded in LocalSettings.php:

`The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
 $wgServer = "http://localhost";`

Replacing with `myserver.mycollege.edu` fixed the problem.